# Applying rolling median across row for pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to apply a rolling median to replace NaN values in the following dataframe, with a window size of 3:

```
 1990      1991      1992      1993      1994      1995      1996      1997      1998      1999      2000      2001      2002      2003      2004  ...      2007      2008      2009       2010       2011       2012       2013       2014       2015       2016       2017       2018       2019  2020  2021

17  366000.0  278000.0  330000.0  NaN  434000.0  470600.0  433000.0  456000.0  556300.0  580200.0  635300.0  690600.0  800000.0  NaN  821500.0  ...  850800.0  905000.0  947500.0  1016500.0  1043900.0  1112800.0  1281900.0  1312700.0  1422000.0  1526900.0  1580000.0  1599000.0  1580000.0   NaN   NaN
```

However pandas `rolling` function seems to work for columns and not along a row. How can i fix this? Also, the solution should NOT change any of the non NAN values in that row

Comment: You can transpose it using `df.T`

Comment: After finding median again transpose it: `df.T.rolling(3).median().T`

Comment: @user308827, you can't do what you want. If you have nan to your series, median will give you nan. Try another strategy. What do you expect for 1993?

Comment: @Corralien, for 1993, it would be the median from the last 3 years (since window size is 3). Isn't there a nanmedian?

Comment: rolling.median already did it. It's the same as np.nanmedian.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First compute the rolling medians by using [**`rolling()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html) with `axis=1` (row-wise), `min_periods=0` (to handle `NaN`), and `closed='both'` (otherwise left edge gets excluded).

Then replace only the `NaN` entries with these medians by using [**`fillna()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html).

```py
medians = df.rolling(3, min_periods=0, closed='both', axis=1).median()
df = df.fillna(medians)

#         1990      1991      1992      1993      1994      1995      1996      1997      1998      1999  ...       2012       2013       2014       2015       2016       2017       2018       2019       2020       2021
# 17  366000.0  278000.0  330000.0  330000.0  434000.0  470600.0  433000.0  456000.0  556300.0  580200.0  ...  1112800.0  1281900.0  1312700.0  1422000.0  1526900.0  1580000.0  1599000.0  1580000.0  1580000.0  1589500.0
```

Comment: a median with nan give nan

Comment: thanks @tdy, your solution changes the non-nan values in the dataframe which is something I do not want

Comment: @user308827 i believe the updated answer does what you're looking for